# How to convert from GenericRecord to SpecificRecord in Avro for compatible schemas

Tags: java, avro

Is the Avro SpecificRecord (i.e. the generated java classes) compatible with schema evolution?  I.e. if I have a source of Avro messages (in my case, kafka) and I want to deserialize those messages to a specificrecord, is it possible to do safely?

What I see:

- adding a field to the end of a schema works fine - can deserialize ok to specificrecord
- adding a field to the middle does not - i.e. breaks existing clients

Even if the messages are compatible, this is a problem.

If I can find the new schema (using e.g. confluent schema registry) I can deserialize to GenericRecord, but there doesn't seem to be a way to map from genericrecord to specificrecord of different schema..

```
MySpecificType message = (T SpecificData.get().deepCopy(MySpecificType.SCHEMA$, genericMessage);
```

Deepcopy is mentioned in various places but it uses index so doesn't work..

Is there any safe way to map between two avro objects when you have both schemas and they are compatible?  Even if I could map from genercrecord to genericrecord this would do as I could then do the deepcopy trick to complete the job.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this? I'm stuck on the same problem, keep getting a "org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Record cannot be cast to org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecord" error...

Comment: I used an AutoMapper class which mapped based on field name.  An example implementation is here: https://gist.github.com/markdav/01623363b5b2508b8e5ef6146caedb1b

Comment: @MarkD Doesn't this `deepCopy` create a huge overhead on the traffic of the system? Doesn't it - in principle - double the load?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are example tests here for specific data type conversion.  Its all in the configuration 'specificDeserializerProps'

https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/avro-serializer/src/test/java/io/confluent/kafka/serializers/KafkaAvroSerializerTest.java

I added the following config and got the specific type out as wanted.

```
HashMap<String, String> specificDeserializerProps = new HashMap<String, String>();
specificDeserializerProps.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, "bogus");
specificDeserializerProps.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SPECIFIC_AVRO_READER_CONFIG, "true");
specificAvroDeserializer = new KafkaAvroDeserializer(schemaRegistry, specificDeserializerProps);
```

Hope that helps

Comment: This deserializer is new.. I'll try it!

Answer (score 2):

By default, KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SPECIFIC_AVRO_READER_CONFIG is set to false, so your KafkaAvroDeserializer will produce a GenericData$Record by default, and not your desired Object (avro generated class).

As @JARC said, you can enable it programatically.

If you are using it in a Spring boot  project, set in this way:

```
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.specific.avro.reader=true
```